# Laravel 5.0 response ajax 404 even it is working fine with successful ajax request

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 
and latest datatable plugin jquery

Some ajax requests are successful and some are not and unsuccessful ajax request
are 404.Pretty Strange
Am I missing anything ?

Note:
After ajax 404 it destroy the session and when I refresh the page it redirect 
me to the login page. even I am using data:'_token = ', in ajax request

My controller method.

```
public function all(Request $request) {
    $draw = $request->get('draw');
    $start = $request->get('start');
    $length = $request->get('length');
    $search = (isset($filter['value']))? $filter['value'] : false;
    $total = \App\Job::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
    $total_members = count($total); // get your total no of data;

    $data = array(
        'recordsTotal' => $total_members,
        'draw' => $draw,
        'data' => $jobsObj,
        'recordsFiltered' => $total_members,
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
    // return response()->json($data);
}
```

When response body is 14,902 bytes it says 404 in ajax request.
Why is that?

my code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';


 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
 });

  // alert( $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  var table =  $('#all-member-table').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100,500,1000 ],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,

    "ajax": {
            url: "/Job/all",
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache : false,
            type  : "GET",
            data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
            // "data": '_token = ' + $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            // beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            //      xhr.setRequestHeader('TOKEN', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
            // }
        },
        "columns": [
        { data: "job_no" },
        { data: "br" },
        { data: "Customer" },
        { data: "Manifest" },
        { data: "HBL" },
        { data: "created_at" },
        { data: "Status" },
        { data: "Options" }
    ]
});


$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().keyup(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length>3) {
        table.search(value).draw();
    } else {
        table.search('').draw();
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: can you share your console output please?

Comment: Instead of doing like this use this package https://datatables.yajrabox.com/
That is easy and simple

Comment: @HasanTareque  output is http://prntscr.com/flyoip

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 14,902 bytes and how did you reach the conclusion that *Not Found* is due to response size?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Its just my observation you can ignore it.